# putty not printing utf-8 characters on serial connection

Tags: utf-8, locale, putty

I am using a serial connection to access the serial port of beagleboard.
The rootfs on beagleboard is using busybox.
I have already set encoding=utf-8 in putty.
When I paste Chinese characters on screen they are converted to "?" but ls is showing correctly.
For example I paste ls 技术笔记 on screen.

```
Linux#> ls ????

技术笔记
```

I wonder why Chinese characters are converted to "??" on copy pasting in putty window.

When I connect to other Linux machine using putty via SSH, there is no problem and the characters are displayed correctly on putty window.

Edit 1:
copy pasting the 1st character, 技, putty generates correct utf-8 code and send it to serial port.
I added printk at the tty layer to print the hexadecimal character received by the tty layer.

```
Linux#>
[ 0][  220.604000] e68a
[ 0][  220.608000] 80?d
-/bin/sh: 技: not found
```

e6 8a 80 is the utf-8 code corresponding to 技.

Answer (score 0):

*NIX:

```
... install locale

locale-gen

dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

---

PuTTY > Settings > Window > Font settings > Font > Change...